# Screen Edge Gesture Recognizer issue

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have problem with UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer. I add .left edge for this gesture for swiping hamburger menu, but I have UISlider control on this screen, which left edge binded to left edge of the screen.
When I swipe from left to right on my UISlider control, instead of changing its value screen shows me hamburger menu.
How to partially disable left edge recognizer in slider area, but stay enable in other parts of this screen?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set a delegate to your `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`,
implement `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithOtherGestureRecognizer` function
and return `false`.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not work for me, I've tried to redefine lots of delegate methods, but all I reached is slowly working slider on the edge: it's hard to catch it to swipe

Comment: Another option is to implement `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer`. This will require you to figure out if the menu gesture and the second one is the slider gesture. and then return false.

Comment: Yes you are right, I implemented this case but it works bad. Slider badly slides, when it located on edge of the screen. Simply say, I turned off left edge gesture on slider area, but when I slides from this edge slider badly slides. I have to correctly point to slider for good working gesture. In other places (when slider thumb shifted from edge) it works good.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented 'require to fail' in overlapping gesture recognizer situations where you don't want a recognizer to respond.

```
leftEdgeRecognizer.require(toFail: sliderAreaRecognizer)
```

This will cause the the left edge swipe to fail or " be disabled" where the slider recognizer is active.